# Como transformar um array de objetos do json em uma List de objetos em c# usando Json.NET

Tags: c#, json

Estou começando a aprender c# e estou apanhando para fazer essa tarefa, pegar um array de objetos de um json e transformar os elementos desse array em objetos de um tipo específico e coloca-los em uma lista. Crie um método que faz isso e retorna uma List de um objeto:

```
private List<Caneta> LerJsonCanetas()
{
    string sJson = null;
    JObject jObject = null;
    List<Caneta> arrCanetas = null;

    arrCanetas = new List<Caneta>();

    //lê o json
    sJson = File.ReadAllText(sArqConfiguracao); //sArqConfiguracao é o caminho para o arquivo json

    jObject = JObject.Parse(sJson);
    JArray sServer = (JArray)jObject["canetas"];

    IList<Caneta> server = jObject["canetas"].ToObject<Caneta[]>();

    foreach (Caneta caneta in server)
    {
        arrCaneta.Add(caneta);
    }

    return arrCaneta;
}
```

Esse é o metodo que criei,não está retornando erro, mas os objetos que estão na lista estão com os atributos null, queria saber como faço para que eu consiga pegar os objetos que estão no array de json e colocalos em objetos do tipo caneta. Estou a dois dias procurando como fazer e não conseguir ainda. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigada.
Ah, esse é meu json:

```
    {
     "tempoexibicao": 10,
     "canetas":
      [
         {
            "cor" : "azul",
            "marca" : "bic"
         },
         {
            "cor" : "vermelha",
            "marca" : "pilot"
         }
      ]

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo que pode ajudar:

```
public class Minhaclasse
{
    public string tempoexibicao { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Canetas> canetas { get; set; }
}

public class Canetas
{
    public string cor { get; set; }
    public string marca { get; set; }
}

class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
    string jsonString = @"{""tempoexibicao"": 10,""canetas"":[{""cor"" : ""azul"",""marca"" : ""bic""},{""cor"" : ""vermelha"",""marca"" : ""pilot""}]}";
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Minhaclasse minhaClasse = serializer.Deserialize<Minhaclasse>(jsonString);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do Carlos, eu também gosto de usar o NewtonSoft
ficando assim:

```
  string jsonString = @"{""tempoexibicao"": 10,""canetas"":[{""cor"" : ""azul"",""marca"" : ""bic""},{""cor"" : ""vermelha"",""marca"" : ""pilot""}]}";
  var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Minhaclasse>(jsonString);
```

Não esqueça de instalar o pacote Nuget do Newtonsoft :)